# extracting an ID in a JSP page (onClick event) in JMETER

Tags: jsp, jmeter

im trying to extrac the 'windowId' in the following code in a jsp page;

```
<button id="finishWizard" onclick="var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); for (var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {if (buttons[i].id == 'finishWizard') buttons[i].disabled=true;}document.forms.WcmPropertiesInfoPage.action='http://172.23.4.23/Workplace/wizards/WcmEntryWizard.jsp?windowId={A15B51EB-76F9-4F98-8FBC-AA0DB8CBC4AE}&eventTarget=WcmWizard&eventName=Finish&eventParam1=0';document.forms.WcmPropertiesInfoPage.submit();document.getElementById('finishWizard').href='';this.disabled=true; return false;" title="To save, click Finish" name="Finish">Finish</button>
```

i need to get the windowId = {A15B51EB-76F9-4F98-8FBC-AA0DB8CBC4AE} which is variable each request. this id is needed to pass it to the next http sample to succesfully complete this 'Finish' button.

how must my regex look like?  i already tried;

```
windowId={(.*)}&eventTarget=WcmWizard&eventName=Finish
```

i tested the above in regex101.com and it matches the ID properly, but i cannot get it work in Jmeter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RegExp Tester which is built into [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener your regex is fine for JMeter as well.

[image: View Results Tree]

Make sure you have "Template" value in your Regular Expression Extractor set to `$1$` and double check resulting variable using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler). See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more information on getting to the bottom of your test errors.